# Place logo in-between menu items

Tags: html, css

I want to put the logo in-between the navigation menus but I can't figure out how to do it in the theme that I have because I'm having trouble finding it in the backend. I'm sure it's just a matter of reordering something or adding a margin and a space for the photo... Under the header section of the CSS this is the code:

```
#header { padding:0 20px;margin-bottom:8px;}

#logo { float:left; }

#logo { text-transform:capitalize; padding:35px 0; }    
#logo img { max-width:100%; }

#navigation { float:right; margin-right:20px; }

#navigation ul { list-style:none; position:relative; }
#navigation ul li { float:left; padding-left:30px; font-size:12px; display:block; position:relative; font-weight:bold; }    
#navigation ul li a { color:#888; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:35px; display:block; }   
#navigation ul li ul { position:absolute; border:1px solid #e9e9e9; display:none; left:15px; padding-bottom:15px; z-index:9999; }   
#navigation ul li ul li {  min-width:150px; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; padding:15px 0 10px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #f6f6f6; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px; }  
#navigation ul li ul li:last-child {  border:0;  padding-bottom:0; }    
#navigation ul li ul li a { border:0; display:block; padding:0; }   
#navigation li:hover ul { display:block; }

#navigation select { display:none; -webkit-appearance: none; border-radius: 0; }

#navigation ul li#magic-line { position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100px; height: 4px; padding-left:0; display:none; }
```

Comment: Would help to see the existing HTML markup so that it's clear what these css rules are affecting.

Comment: What's your browser support requirements for this project? Flexbox can provide a good solution for your problem.

Comment: @ChrisDisley Read my comment to Goran. I'm not entirely sure where to find the html codes which is part of the problem

Comment: @steffcarrington The usual: safari, firefox, IE, etc. Is flexbox a plugin?

Comment: @newsoul flexbox is a CSS3 layout module that is used to create complex layout with ease in modern browsers. It's not a plugin. There's an informative article on it on the CSS tricks website - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose u are using wordpress theme ? If so, each li has its own classes. So you should create one "empty" menu, and add it as background of that link, you can make link to be home page. Text you can hide with text-indent:-9999px;

If u have exact link, i can be more helpful, check how i pulled it out here: http://itsgoran.com/cider

Update:

code should be like this:

```
li#menu-item-15 {
    background-image: url(http://www.new.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SHEISBIDDYmainlogoandslogan1.png);
    width: 470px;
    height: 130px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

but i suggest firstly to create smaller logo image, then use that image for this, and ofcourse add smaller width and height which would be width/height of that smaller image.

Comment: I am using a wordpress theme... I came into this project after someone else had chosen the theme and began messing with it so it's been really difficult to figure out where anything is. Any idea where I should put the empty menu? I have about thirty choices! (Also those ciders sound amazing)

Comment: Depends where logo should be, if its at the start place it as first menu item, then add class to that element inside menu screen(if you dont see class attribute box, turn it on - top right "screen" link).After that in style.css add something like:

#menu li.logo a {
display:inline-block;
width:width of logo image
height: height of logo image
background-image:url(logo image here)
}

and play around to adjust it. Hard to give exact without seeing site.

Comment: This was under Style Dynamic HTML. Think it's what we need? 
#logo          { float:none; padding-bottom:0; }
#logo img         { display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding-right:20px; }
#navigation        { float:none; width:100%; text-align:center; }
#navigation ul        { margin-left:-30px; }
#navigation ul li       { float:none; display:inline-block; position:relative;}
#navigation ul li       { padding-bottom:<?php echo $of_option[$prefix.'header_navspace'] ?>px; }
#navigation ul li ul      { text-align:left; }
#navigation ul li ul li:first-child  { margin-left:15px; }

Comment: Well the logo is now in line with the navigation but it's at the front instead of the middle. Did I insert the code into the wrong place?

Comment: just move home menu item in wordpress menu page to the middle.

Comment: Awesome! Just mark answer as correct when u get time.